# Python: how to find wrapped function parameter in decorator?

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a decorated along these lines:

```
from functools import wraps

def mark_something(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        # How do I find the pd.DataFrame parameter of the decorated function?
        # df = args[<pos_1>] or kwargs['df']
        df = df.apply(lambda x: ...)

        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

The wrapped method receives a `DatFrame` parameter as the 2nd parameter.

The problem is that the caller can do either `foo(something, my_df)` and then I need to look in `args` or `foo(something, df=my_df)` and I need to look in `kwargs`.

Is there a "nice" way to find a parameter in the wrapped function **without** having to explicitly check both dictionary and list?

**EDIT**

I tried `kwargs.get('df', args[1])` but that throws an error since `args` has a single item ... I thought that optional part is evaluated **only** if get fails ...

Comment: Can you include an example of how you actually want to use this? Specifically what is foo and how did you declare it.

Comment: Also, what is `wraps` you should probably include that definition/ where you get it from.

Comment: "I thought that optional part is evaluated only if get fails" no you're making a method call with two arguments, both of those arguments need to be resolved. You could use defaultdict from collections. `z = defaultdict(lambda: args[1])` then args[1] won't get checked until z needs a default look up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your decorator is very specific, ie it has a dataframe and a single non-keyword argument, you could use the correct argument signature in your decorator method.

```
def wrapper(fun):
    def working(a, kwd=None):
        print("arg: ", a)
        print("kwarg: ", kwd)

        return fun(a, kwd)
    return working

@wrapper
def testme(a, kwd=None):
    print("running: ", a, kwd)

testme(1, 2)
testme(1, kwd=3)
```

The output is then:

> arg:  1
>   kwarg:  2
>   running:  1 2
>   arg:  1
>   kwarg:  3
>   running:  1 3

Of course this could be improved by add `@wraps` from functools, but I think the idea is there.

Comment: your suggestion would limit using the decorator on method's with the exact same signature -- right? (parameter names as well?)

Comment: @mibm yes, but your requirements seem to be that you need to have a dataframe. You could capture remaining arguments etc.